# How to deploy single artifacts to multiple web app in Dev-ops Release Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have one release pipeline where i am deploying latest/selected artifacts to one web app.
I want to release the same artifacts to multiple web app in single release pipeline.

I have two option in my mind.

1. Create a multiple task with each web app. (this is achievable but every time pipeline changes requires whenever there is new web app getting in picture)
2. using Power shell but not sure why my command is not working here . getting error as **The term 'Publish-AzWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,** Though this command is working fine in local system but not in pipeline.

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName gggroup -Name $app -ArchivePath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip
```

**this command will run in loop.**

Any suggestion!!!

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my answer and hope it can help you~

Comment: Hi @JaneMa-MSFT thanks for the reply . It was the version issue in Devops command and now i am able to do deploy the package into multiple web app in powershell loops.

Comment: Hi @JaneMa-MSFT SCM also helped me lot for accessing the file after and before deployment to web app But i don't want this feature to be enable for my  web app as per security concern. Do you know how to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For option 2, `Publish-AzWebApp` is a step for classic deployment. However, modules for classic deployment are not supported in PowerShell task of Azure DevOps services any more.

Instead, you can use the [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops).

Also, you can deploy ZIP file with REST APIs then invoke the REST APIs using PowerShell.

```
POST https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

The `POST` request must contain the .zip file in the message body. The deployment credentials for your app are provided in the request by using HTTP BASIC authentication. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#rest) for detailed information.

Comment: I have just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53222386/14026068) provide a sample script of invoking the REST API.